# Does Orisa's "Halt!" activate when it hits someone?

Tags: overwatch

"Halt!" activates when the right mouse button is pressed again or it hits a "surface"

https://overwatch.gamepedia.com/Orisa#cite_note-3

What about if it hits an enemy? Say I am firing halt to a group of enemies without bothering to press the right button again. Will it work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, Halt! will pass right through enemies and barriers, and only automatically detonate against solid surfaces.